# Counting Unique Records based on Name and Time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns which have a Record, Name, and Time Stamp.

I would like to count all unique records sent by one person for 6 AM.

Here is an example of my table

```
Name    Record  stamp
ROBERT  589043  6/19/19 6:12 AM
CHARLES 354134  6/19/19 6:21 AM
DAVID   999900  6/19/19 6:40 AM
EVAN    164134  6/19/19 6:43 AM
CHARLES 888800  6/19/19 6:46 AM
EVAN    164134  6/19/19 6:48 AM
DAVID   111254  6/19/19 6:56 AM
A-ROD   454544  6/19/19 6:57 AM
CHARLES 354134  6/19/19 6:59 AM
```

I would like to see is

```
Name    Unique Records at 6 AM
ROBERT  1
CHARLES 2
DAVID   2
EVAN    1
A-ROD   1
```

I used

`=SUMPRODUCT((HOUR(C1:C9)=6)*(E5:E9="CHARLES"))`

But this formula only gives me the 3 times "CHARLES" appeared on my list. How can I incorporate adding a count considering the unique records?

Comment: You could use a Pivot Table.  Probably need a column called `Hour` (`=HOUR(C2)`) and, when you Insert the Pivot Table, select to `add to Data Model`. This will give a `Value` option for `Distinct Count`

Comment: I need my values in specific fields. So creating a Pivot table is possible and can result to my solution but it also requires more steps than a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do this by formula:

[image]

Formula in cell `F2`:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(($A$2:$A$10=E2)*(HOUR($C$2:$C$10)=6),MATCH($B$2:$B$10,$B$2:$B$10,0)),ROW($B$2:$B$10)-ROW($B$2)+1)>0))
```

Entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

But like Ron Rosenfeld mentioned, a Pivot Table is generally more suited for such work.

Comment: This is great! Thank you JvdV!